# ')' Expected (java)

Tags: java, compiler-construction, syntax

I seem to be getting a *')' Expected* error when I am trying to compile the program

I am not sure what the problem is, as there are no ) missing in the section of code it is indicating is wrong. Below is the code

```
public void openBankAccount (String firstName, String lastName, String addr1,
                             String addr2, String addr3,
                             String postcode, double openingBalance)
{
    // Hilighted line
    this.account = new BankAccount(String firstName, String lastName,
                                   String addr1, String addr2, String addr3,
                                   String postcode, double openingBalance);


}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to specify the types of the constructor arguments again, as they're already defined by the constructor signature again:

```
new BankAccount(firstName, lastName,addr1, addr2, addr3, postcode, openingBalance);
```

Comment: @Chris, Thats not the issue here. In the call to your constructor, there is no need to specify the type, i.e `String` or `double`, just use the variables.